# Visual Studio Coded UI Test for Kendo UI

Tags: kendo-ui, coded-ui-tests

Is there a way for VS2013 Coded UI test to work on Kendo UI?

Specially for combobox where it will be read as span element and not select.

Thanks.

Comment: The value from the widget is stored in a hidden (display is set to none) input. You can get the value from there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a utility functions to handle such controls. refer below function for kendodrop down for selenium C#. same can be written in CodedUI

```
 public static void KendoDropDown(string id, string name, string Value, IWebDriver Driver)
        {
            IWebElement Input = Driver.FindElement(By.Id(id));
            Input.Click();

            //put some wait

            IWebElement levelBox = Driver.FindElement(By.Id(name));
            var OptionsList = levelBox.FindElements(By.TagName("li"));
            foreach (var DropdownOption in OptionsList)
            {
                if (DropdownOption.Text.Contains(Value))
                {
                    DropdownOption.Click();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

it has three part to interact with Dropdown arrow, list box and list items.